# Is there a direct way to convert Unix Time on Informix to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

Tags: sql, informix, unix-timestamp

I know something like this can be accomplished easily using PHP or Perl, but I want to know if there's a way to do it directly on Informix, something like the function `FROM_UNIXTIME()` on MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it using dbinfo with 'utc_to_datetime' as a parameter: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1484.htm